# Grab first <tr> & <a> if <table> contains <a>

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm stuck on a Simple HTML Dom question...

For each `<table>` on my webpage I'd like to scan the `<table>` and check if there is an `<a>` inside of it. If there is, then echo the first `<tr>` and `<a>` else skip and go on to the end `<table>`.

I started working on it but I'm unsure how to progress or check if there is a `<a>` in the table...

```
foreach ($html->find('table') as $name) {
    foreach ($name->find('a') as $elem) {
        echo $elem->plaintext.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For jquery-like libraries it's `table:has(a) tr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've shared seems very close. See below to output the first child `<tr>` of the table, if an `<a>` element is found, then stop looping through additional `<a>` elements. What specific problems are you having with your code?

```
foreach ($html->find('table') as $name) {
    foreach ($name->find('a') as $elem) {
        echo $name->find('tr', 0)->plaintext; // echo first TR element
        echo $elem->plaintext.'<br>'; // echo A element
        break 1; // skip to the next table
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh, I guess I was pretty close because the code you provided worked perfectly. Thank you so much!